# HTML + JS image viewer not loading images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

So I found this piece of code: https://gist.github.com/NoUsername/9308327

I downloaded it as zip, created a new folder name "images"in the root directory (same folder where I put the HTML file), and added some jpg pics in it. But when I opened the HTML file, the images won't load.

Is something wrong with the code?

P/S: When I changed the source of the  tag to "/images/<1st pic's name>.jpg", the 1st image showed up just fine, though.

Comment: *"But when I opened the HTML file, the images won't load."* - Any errors? Did it try to load the images? What did the network tab and the console in your dev tools say?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this script assumes you have enabled directory listing feature of apache for `/images`

See https://support.tigertech.net/directory-index

When you access http://your.server/images it should show a list of the files as a html page. This script uses this list to get the image urls and render them.

To enable the feature you need to create a `.htaccess` file inside `/images` with the options provided in the documentation link.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer of @venimus doesn't work. Be sure about your image path. You can use fullpath istead of "/iamges", like "http://localhost/image_directory". Last of all If you image's extension in uppercase like "image.PNG" it can't find your images.